# Recursive function for building array from tree

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, tree

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 23
        [name] => testasdf
        [depth] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 26
        [name] => asdf
        [depth] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 31
        [name] => Another level deep
        [depth] => 3
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 32
        [name] => Another level deep
        [depth] => 2
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 24
        [name] => testasdf
        [depth] => 1
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 27
        [name] => asdf
        [depth] => 1
    )
)
```

Here is the recursive function that I'm using, it works except in some cases (where the depth is greater it seems.

```
function process(&$arr, &$prev_sub = null, $cur_depth = 1) {
    $cur_sub = array();
    while($line = current($arr)){
        if($line['depth'] < $cur_depth){
            return $cur_sub; 
        }elseif($line['depth'] > $cur_depth){
            $prev_sub = $this->process($arr, $cur_sub, $cur_depth + 1 );
        }else{
            $cur_sub[$line['term_id']] = array('term_id' => $line['term_id'], 'name' => $line['name']);
            $prev_sub =& $cur_sub[$line['term_id']];
            next($arr);
        }
    }
    return $cur_sub;
}
```

This is how the results look:

```
Array
(
    [23] => Array
    (
        [26] => Array
        (
            [31] => Array
            (
                [term_id] => 31
                [name] => Another level deep
            )
        )
        [32] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 32
            [name] => Another level deep
        )
    )
    [24] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 24
        [name] => testasdf
    )
    [27] => Array
    (
        [term_id] => 27
        [name] => asdf
    )
)
```

Any idea how I can have it so the term_id and name is shown for all depths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function process(&$arr, &$prev_sub = null, $cur_depth = 1) {

  $cur_sub = array();
    while($line = current($arr)){
        if($line['depth'] < $cur_depth){
            return $cur_sub; 
        }
        if($line['depth'] > $cur_depth){
            $prev_sub = $this->process($arr, $cur_sub, $cur_depth + 1 );

        }

            $cur_sub[$line['term_id']] = array('term_id' => $line['term_id'], 'name' => $line['name']);
            $prev_sub =& $cur_sub[$line['term_id']];
            next($arr);
    }
  return $cur_sub;
}
```

Comment: This actually matched up the right ID's, I think before the term_id's being returned in the wrong order, but it still doesn't show the term_id and name values for the first two nodes, it seems any node that has children, doesn't get the term_id and name array added